# Showing that the following function is O of the other

Tags: sequences-and-series, computational-complexity

I have the following functions: $f_1= $ $n\choose{0.5n}$ and $f_2 = (\log\log n)^{\log n}$. Im trying to prove that $f_2=O(f_1)$.
I simplified $f_2$ to the following: $f_2 = (\log\log n)^{\log n}=2^{\log((\log(\log(n)){}^{\log n}))}=2^{\log(n)*\log((\log(\log(n))))}$
and approximated $f_1$ using Sterlings approximation to the following:$\frac{2^{n}}{\sqrt{n}}\leq f_{1}$.
so, I'm left with **showing that**: **$2^{\log(n)*\log((\log(\log(n))))}\leq \frac{2^{n}}{\sqrt{n}}$**. 
I tried to prove that $2^{\log(n)*\log((\log(\log(n))))}\leq 2^{0.5n}$ but cant seem to make progress. Help is much appreciated. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was using the fact that $log(n)=O(n^\epsilon)$.